Scary movie with a couple whose car breaks down and they get help from a family in a farmhouse
All I remember is that a couple's car breaks down on the side of the road. They end up getting help from a family in a farmhouse and stay in the house. But then the family traps them in the basement and wants to kill them. The slave who works on the farm tries to help the family escape but when he gets caught by the owner, they cut his eyes out. And at the end of the movie, the family reveals they are aliens or something and rise into a bright light.
I want to say the year was before 2009, maybe early 2000s. I think the couple spoke English. Can't rememeber if the farm people did. And it was gory. And no, it wasn't Breakdown.

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

Approximate year\decade? Country\language? Where\when did you see it? Was it gory or psychological?

Could it be Breakdown?

I want to say the year was before 2009, maybe early 2000s. I think the couple spoke English. Can't rememeber if the farm people did. And it was gory. And no it wasn't breakdown

Maybe Farmhouse with Steven Weber & Kelly Hu-
Farmhouse is a psychological thriller set in the modern day mid-west. We follow a young couple as they leave their everyday lives behind and head out to a new beginning; starting over from scratch. After becoming stranded in an isolated Wine Vineyard in the middle of nowhere, the young couple is forced to face the secrets they're running from, all the while trying to escape the malicious intent of the Vineyard mysterious inhabitants.
